Does Fourier series work for jump discontinuities?
Suppose, I have the function,
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x, & \text{if } 0\leq x < 0 \\
-(x+\pi), & \text{if } -\pi\leq x < 0
\end{cases},\ f(x)=f(x+2\pi)
$$
This function appears to have jump discontinuities.

I have been assigned to find the Fourier series, but considering that this function has jump discontinuities, I am doubtful as to whether the Fourier series will converge or not.
Will the Fourier series converge to the function?

Yes, the Fourier series will evaluate to the midpoint between the jumps at the discontinuity.  I am sure you have looked at square waves.  That is a function with a jump discontinuity.  In fact, I think you can model the wave above as a sum of a triangle wave and a square wave.

This is the Gibbs phenomenon. You should read more about it.

Fourier Theorem states that for every sectionally differentiable function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of period $2L$, the Fourier series of $f$ converges, and moreover we have that
$$
\frac{1}{2}a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( a_n \cos{\frac{n \pi x}{L}} + b_n \sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\lim_{y \to x^{+}} f(y) + \lim_{z \to x^{-}} f(z) \right)
$$
which, graphically, is the midpoint between both one-sided limits of your function.
Here, we say that $f$ is sectionally differentiable if $f$ and $f'$ (where it exists) have finite discontinuities of first kind in every bounded interval.
You can read more about all of this formalisms in "Análise de Fourier e Equações Diferenciais Parciais" by Djairo Guedes de Figueiredo, which i think is an amazing book to start learning Fourier series.
